# Is there a way to pass a stream to some external component while maintaining ownership over that stream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, filestream

I have an application which reads a specific file format. Additionally, the application supports "plugins" which read alternate file formats, and convert them into the standardized format the tool natively supports.

I would like to define an interface something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for file transformer. Implementers of this interface provide a means to
/// convert a given file into Foo Format.
/// </summary>
public interface IFileTransformerPlugin
{
    /// <summary>Gets the name of the transformer to display to the user.</summary>
    /// <value>The name of the transformer displayed to the user.</value>
    string DisplayName
    {
        get;
    }

    /// <summary>Determines if this transformer can handle the given format.</summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method should return very quickly; reading only a small portion of the
    /// input stream. This method is intended to be a rough cut check -- returning true
    /// does not necessarily mean that the file will parse successfully on full load.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="fileContents">The file contents.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if this transformer can handle the supplied format, false otherwise.
    /// </returns>
    bool CanHandleLogFormat(Stream fileContents);

    /// <summary>Transforms a file into Foo Format.</summary>
    /// <param name="inputFile">The input log stream.</param>
    /// <param name="outputFile">The output log stream (where the output should be
    /// written).</param>
    /// <returns>A transformation result which includes error information.</returns>
    LogTransformationResult Transform(Stream inputFile, Stream outputFile);
}
```

The problem comes from the transform method taking streams. Conceptually, I would like the plugin host, rather than the plugin, to "own" these streams, and be responsible for calling IDispose or whatever on these streams. For instance, under testing scenarios it would be nice for the caller to be able to pass a MemoryStream as the output, and then verify that the output is valid.

However, as a plugin author, it is desirable to be able to use the upper level formatting constructs in the framework; namely TextReader/TextWriter; XmlTextReader/XmlTextWriter; etc. But these classes take ownership of the underlying stream and call Dispose on the underlying stream, regardless of what the code providing the stream does. (At least, assuming those classes themselves are disposed correctly)

How might I rework this interface to get around this problem? Is it even a solvable problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This invokes the classic software engineering line: "every problem can be solved with an extra level of indirection".  Just wrap the stream and provide one-liner methods that delegate to the base stream.  Except for the Dispose method, do nothing so that whatever the client code does, you keep control of the stream.  Like:

```
public class OwnedStream : Stream {
    private Stream stream;
    public OwnedStream(Stream stream) { this.stream = stream; }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        // Do nothing
    }
    public override bool CanRead { get { return stream.CanRead; } }

    // etcetera, just delegate to "stream"
}
```

Do note the other side of that medal: you are handing a reference to other code.  It can store it, you'll have no idea when they are done with it.

Comment: +1 for the approach, +1 for the caveat. Alas, I have only 1 +1 to give.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really liked that closing the reader/writer closes the stream (for exactly the reason you describe.)  I usually work around this by passing the readers/writers rather than the streams.  Generally you want to control the format of the stream anyway (text vs. binary) and the XmlTextReader/Writer can be instantiated from a provided TextReader/Writer, so now it's just a matter of deciding whether you give your plugin a Binary or Text accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the stream object accessible via a getter in the interface?  Then your application can get the stream reference from the implementation whenever it needs it.

```
public interface IFileTransformerPlugin {
  string DisplayName { get; }
  string Stream inputFile { get; }

  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Because then the interface implementer provides the stream, and I would like the interface caller to provide it. That is, today this app happens to write the transformed file to disk. But tomorrow I/we might decide we want to do everything in memory, and I don't want clients to break in that case.

Comment: Also, this just flips the problem around -- now the plugin is handing over a stream, and presumably the host wants to be able to create TextReaders or whatever, and they can't.

Comment: So you really meant you want the host to be responsible for creating the streams.

Comment: Yes, that's why in my example the streams are passed in to the interface as parameters.

Comment: Seems to me you need to expect that the streams may not persist when you pass them into the plugin.  I would create streams explicitly for that purpose and then test whether they are still active when the call returns.

Comment: That strategy only works for e.g. file streams, where you can go back to the data store and create ones if necessary. If it is a MemoryStream, for instance, once the stream is gone, so is the data. There is no way to recover from the stream being destroyed.

Comment: What I meant is that you would create a stream explicitly to pass in.  This could (should) be a copy of whatever data you want the plugin to control.  If the plugin destroys it before sending it back then you still have the original version (and the plugin apparently didn't care to send back updates since it destroyed it).

Comment: What about the output stream, from which the plugin returns the associated data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15991/discussion-between-peter-gluck-and-billy-oneal)

Comment: What about it?  If they have some data to return then they shouldn't close it.  If they do close it then they either didn't want to send anything back or it's an error in their implementation, right?  At some point you need to have some kind of user guide/API that you're working to.  You could also use some kind of design by contract framework to enforce that the output stream still exists when the plugin returns.